# Beautifying a table produced by PHP with Ext

Tags: javascript, extjs, html-table, xampp

I have some code in HTML, PHP, and MySQL. I have an input form with some checkboxes and text boxes. Submitting the form runs a PHP script which generates an HTML page with a `<table>` on it with some data rows.

The PHP code is calling many scripts and functions to dynamically create a MySQL query and runs it.

I want to beautify my table and forms using [Ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS), but I am a beginner to XAMPP and totally new to Ext.

1. HTML input form
2. Table

I would like to fix the table first, but how do I do this?

Currently I am doing:

```
echo '<html><table><tr>........</html>' // in PHP.
```

Any examples would be nice.

Comment: Could you attach your code to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "[From Markup Grid Example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2/examples/grid/transform-dom.html)" in the ExtJS examples, the relevant bit is in `transform-dom.js` and is:

```
// create the grid
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.ux.grid.TransformGrid', "the-table", {
    stripeRows: true,
    height: 130
});
grid.render();
```

Basically, this takes an existing table with an id of `the-table` and turns it into an ExtJS grid.